# If $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and $f(T)=a_0I_V+a_1T+a_2T^2+...+a_kT^k$, then $f(T)$ is also a linear operator on $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Definition:** $f(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+...+a_kt^k \in \mathbb{K}[t]$

If $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $V$, then

$$f(T)=a_0I_V+a_1T+a_2T^2+...+a_kT^k$$

Analogous for matrices of $n\times n$.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a $K-$vector space $V$ and $f(t)\in K[t]$.

1. $f(T)$ is also a linear operator on $V$.
2. If $V$ is finite dimensional and $\beta$ is a basis for $V$, then $[f(T)]_\beta=f([T]_\beta)$

For $1$, shall I prove the conditions for what is meant by a linear operator? If so, I'm not quite sure how to do it.

For $2$, I have the following:

\begin{align*}
[f(T)]_\beta &= [a_0I_v+a_1T+...a_nT^n]_\beta \\
&=a_0[I_V]_\beta +a_1[T]\beta +...+a_n[T^n]_\beta \\
&=a_0I+a_1[T]_\beta +...+a_n([T]_\beta)^n \\
&=f([T]_\beta)
\end{align*}

Comment: For 1. just observe that $f(T)$ is a linear combination of linear operators $I_V,T,T^2,\dpts$.

Comment: What is $[f(T)]_\beta$?

Comment: @jasnee For a linear operator $T$, the notation $[T]_\beta$ denotes the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding 1: You have to show that for any vectors $v,w \in V$, the following holds: $f(T)(v+w)=f(T)(v)+f(T)(w)$ and $f(T)(\lambda v) = \lambda f(T)(v)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$. I suggest you take as a warm-up exercise $f(T) = T+T^2$ to see what happens. Then, you'll be able to prove the general statement.

If you get stuck again, feel free to let me know!

**Edit**: You want to prove by induction that $T^n(v+w)=T^n(v)+T^n(w)$. The base case $T^1(v+w)=T^1(v)+T^1(w)$ is clear. Assume that $T^i(v+w)=T^i(v)+T^i(w)$ holds for all $i\leq n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (this is our induction hypothesis). Then,
$$
T^{n+1}(v+w) = T(T^n(v+w)) \stackrel{(*)}{=} T(T^n(v)+T^n(w)) = T^{n+1}(v)+T^{n+1}(w),
$$
where we used the induction hypothesis in step $(*)$. Now, we are able to show that $f(T)(v+w)=f(T)(v)+f(T)(w)$ for general
$$
f(T) = \sum_{n=0}^ka_nT^n
$$
as follows:
\begin{align}
f(T)(v+w) &= \sum_{n=0}^ka_nT^n(v+w)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^ka_n\big(T^n(v)+T^n(w)\big)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^ka_nT^n(v) + \sum_{n=0}^ka_nT^n(w)\\
&= f(T)(v)+f(T)(w),
\end{align}
where the second equality follows from what we had shown earlier.

Comment: Done. To prove the general statement, is it by induction?

Comment: Yes, an inductive argument should do the trick.

Comment: Now, I have a problem in the inductive step...

Comment: I have added the proof. Is it clear now?